# The results of logistic regression (forward selection) analysis in R are different from those in SPSS

Tags: r, logistic-regression, spss, forward

First image is the results in SPSS.
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cspF9.png)

And this is the R code for the analysis (logistic regression-forward selection)

```
#stepwise logistic regression
    fullmod<- 
      glm(Grouping~Age+ODI+B+C+E+D+F+G+H+J+K+L,data=data1,family=binomial)
    nothing<-glm(Grouping~1, data=data1, family=binomial) 
    summary(nothing)
    forwards = 
      step(nothing,scope=list(lower=formula(nothing),upper=formula(fullmod)), 
       direction="forward")
    summary(forwards)
    round(exp(forwards$coefficients),3)
    round(exp(confint(forwards)),3)
```

Second image is the result of the R code.
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od1VP.png)

As you see, a new variable(E variable in second image) was added in the result of R.

I am very confused with this conflicting results.

Which result (SPSS or R)  should I choose?

Thank you for your attention in my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the R step documentation, it's adding predictors based on the AIC. In SPSS Statistics LOGISTIC REGRESSION it's done based on the p values for score statistics.

Comment: I am very sorry to respond to your comment late. Thank you for your advice. From your answer, I understood that the mechanism of calculation is different between the  two methods.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, in that the variable selection is based on different statistics. In models where the same variables are selected, I would expect things to match up in terms of coefficients, etc.